# mysql limit error when selecting from two tables

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to add a limit to this sql, it was working fine before the limit but as soon as I add the limit I get an error that says

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 0,10' at line 1

My sql is

```
SELECT a.id,a.product_name,a.product_price,a.user_id as product_user_id,b.id as user_id,b.first_name, FROM products as a, customers as b where a.user_id=b.id and a.product_featured='Y' and a.product_status='Active' order by a.id desc limit 0,6
```

Comment: Your query says "limit 0,6" but your error says "LIMIT 0,10". Is this a typo or is the error coming from a different query?

Comment: Noit a typo, I noticed that and for some reason dismissed it as a generic error from mysql but now that I think about it thats not right, must be something in the database class i'm using

Answer (score 1):

You have a query error not in limit but before the keyword `FROM` you have put a comma `,`. Remove that and your query will run.

You query is

```
SELECT a.id,a.product_name,a.product_price,a.user_id as product_user_id,b.id as user_id,b.first_name, FROM products as a, customers as b where a.user_id=b.id and a.product_featured='Y' and a.product_status='Active' order by a.id desc limit 0,6
```

Chagne it to

```
SELECT a.id,a.product_name,a.product_price,a.user_id as product_user_id,b.id as user_id,b.first_name FROM products as a, customers as b where a.user_id=b.id and a.product_featured='Y' and a.product_status='Active' order by a.id desc limit 0,6
```

Remove `,` before keyword `FROM`.

Answer (score 0):

You have placed comma at wrong place remove it and than execute the query:

```
SELECT a.id,a.product_name,a.product_price,a.user_id AS product_user_id,b.id AS user_id,b.first_name**,** FROM products AS a, customers AS b WHERE a.user_id=b.id AND a.product_featured='Y' AND a.product_status='Active' ORDER BY a.id DESC LIMIT 0,6
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the comma before the `From` keyword and it will work.

The correct query will be

```
SELECT a.id,a.product_name,a.product_price,a.user_id as product_user_id,b.id as user_id,b.first_name FROM products as a, customers as b where a.user_id=b.id and a.product_featured='Y' and a.product_status='Active' order by a.id desc limit 0,6
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, didnt realise there was a limit already added

Comment: How is this solved? You have an error in query. Before keword `from` you have placed a comma. I am asnotished how that query is running out.